# md5 encrypted password with phpMailer issue

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [md5 password with phpMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118711/md5-password-with-phpmailer)

Hello everybody and thanks in advance for reading this.
I have stored in my database in md5 format the password of an email account. Then when i send a notification email to the webmaster through phpMailer using the following code i get an stmp connection failed error. The same code without md5 encryption works perfectly.

```
  $mail = new PHPMailer(); 
  $mail->IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
  $mail->Username = $USR_EMAIL; // SMTP username
  $mail->Password = md5($MAIL_PWD); // SMTP password
  .
  .
  .
```

Anyone has any idea why wont send emails with an md5 password? Should i change something to class.phpMailer? Thank you for reading this

Comment: Why do you think hashing the password would work? Does your MTA's documentation explicitly say that a simple hash of the password would work?

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that you're double-hashing the password. As you say, it's stored in the database in md5 format, and then you md5 it again, so you're in effect doing:

```
$passwd = 'hello';
$mail->Password = md5(md5($passwd));
```

Maybe

```
$mail->Password = $MAIL_PWD;
```

will work.

However, note that you mostly CAN'T send the md5 hash to the mail server and have it work. The server will then do its own hashing/crypting of the pasword text you send, and the md5 of a password is very much different from the actual password. You need to send over the REAL raw text of the password, not a hashed version.

Comment: The idea was actually to unmd5 the password by doing md5($MAIL_PWD) but as i see that cant be done actually. I am just a little worried of having an email password not encrypted in a database.

Comment: md5 is a one-way hash. consider it the equivalent of cow->hamburger. You can **NOT** turn the hamburger back into a cow.

Answer (score 1):

You say the password in your database is stored in MD5 format. If I then look at the flow you do now is:

Database (Password in MD5) -> PHP Code (Password ***convert to MD5***) (Access SMTP)

At the point where you do: convert to MD5 you practically do this: md5(md5("password")). If I do that in my Terminal I get:

```
localhost:~ user$ md5 -s password
MD5 ("password") = 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
localhost:~ user$ md5 -s 696d29e0940a4957748fe3fc9efd22a3
MD5 ("5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99") = 696d29e0940a4957748fe3fc9efd22a3
```

If this is not your case, then maybe try to look into that Password method in the PHPMailer source if it already converts to MD5. Maybe it's setting in the Class/Object too to choose what hashing method to use?